# Elastic search find messages which contain instead of match

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am performing search like this:

```
SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch(INDEX_NAME)
             .setSearchType(SearchType.DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH)
             .setQuery(QueryBuilders.termsQuery(TAG_NAME,badWords))
             .execute()
             .actionGet();
```

"badWords" in the termSearhc is defined as a Set.

the words which are defined in the badWords are like "OR" operator which mean that a hit is counted on each match of one of the words defined in badWords.

It works fine for me, but what i want is that the search will find words in the text that contain  one of the badWords items no need foe exact matching.

For example if the badWords contain: {like, watch}

For the text: "i liked watching" the result will be 0 because it will not detect a match.
How can i solve this? what query to use?

Comment: I suggest reading [this section of the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/partial-matching.html). Your question is too broad given the requirements. Play with those types of queries, if you have issues then post again a more specific question.

Comment: @AndreiStefan thanks,. maybe I didn't explained my self well, I simply looking for a search which act as a "contain" and not "match". I looked in the wild card example but my problem is that it dont support Set value as the search "value" only String. Prefix query is close but I am looking for contain which can be in the middle or end of word.

Comment: `query_string` with wildcard then. But beware of the performance hit. And you also have nGrams to look at ;-).